# Spring batch - repeat steps for a set of csv

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a requirement where we have multiple csv files read by Spring batch. I need to process it in a way where 1 file is read, processed and written and then other is picked and so on. The number of lines inside csv files vary and currently the lines are read one by one irrespective of the csv file. What spring batch attribute should I use. Since I am new to Spring batch, would appreciate an elaborated answer.

Comment: Are all the CSVs formatted the same?

Comment: yes all CSVs have the same format...i tried using multiresourcepartitioner..it is working but it is not serving the code flow already written...so are there any other ways in spring batch to do this?

Comment: Just to confirm, you're asking for one output file per input file?